# Monitoring CPU usage by user

Tags: monitoring

I'm looking for a tool which monitors the CPU usage (or CPU time) of all real/logged-in users and which provides some kind of graphical representation of the accumulated data, e.g., a graph of CPU usage per user over time.

Comment: Can the answer here do the job: https://serverfault.com/questions/395801/graphing-per-user-cpu-usage-on-a-linux-machine?

Answer (score 1):

Do either of these work?:

- [vtop](https://github.com/MrRio/vtop)
- [ptop](https://github.com/black-perl/ptop)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ganglia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganglia/)

Reference: [Ganglia Gmetric repository](http://vuksan.com/linux/ganglia/)

Comment: Are you sure that Ganglia provides a function to display CPU usage **per user**?